# Django + AJAX, need to click buttom twice to works

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

trying to develop a single page to perform the CRUD I chose to use nav-tabs, I am using AJAX to navigate between them and load the content, the part of creating an object is happening correctly, however, when I click in the edit button i need to click twice for him to execute the changeTAB () function that has the logic of switching to the CREATE / UPDATE tab.

I do not imagine how to solve this problem.

index.html:

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>CRUD EXAMPLE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Ordens de Serviço</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a class="js-list"
                          data-toggle="tab"
                          href="#list"
    >
      Ordens de Serviço</a></li>

    <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="js-create-update"
           data-url="{% url 'example:create' %}"
           id="tab-create-update"

           href="#create-update"
    >
      Create/Update</a></li>

    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#detail">Ver</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="list" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Equipamentos</h3>
      {% include 'example/list.html' %}
    </div>

    <div id="create-update" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Criar/Editar</h3>
        {% include 'example/create.html' %}

    </div>
    <div id="detail" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Detalhes</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="{% static 'js/example.js' %}"> </script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

list.html:

```
<table class="table" id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>TAG</th>
        <th>nivel</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {%for equipamento in equipamentos %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{equipamento.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{equipamento.tag}}</td>
        <td>{{equipamento.nivel}}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary js-update-object"
                    data-url="{% url 'example:update' equipamento.id %}"
                    onclick=changeTab()
            >Update</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

update.html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'example:update' form.instance.pk %}" class="js-update-form">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {% include 'example/form.html' %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update/Save</button>
</form>
```

example.js

```
//essa função vai carregar o form assim que clicar na tab de criar/editar
$(function () {
    //carrega o formulário
    var loadForm =function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        $("#create-update").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  };


    //carrega a tabela assim que clicar na tab da lista
   $(".js-list").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/list/',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            $("#list").html(data.html_list);
          }
        });
    });



//salva o formulário.
      var saveForm =function () {
      var form = $(this)
      $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.form_is_valid) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/create/',
              type: 'get',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
                $("#create-update").html(data.html_form);
              }
            });
        }
        else {
          $("#create-update").html(data.html_form);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };

//create equipamentes
 $(".js-create-update").click(loadForm);
 $("#create-update").on("submit", ".js-create-form", saveForm );

//atualizar

 $("#create-update").on("submit", ".js-update-form", saveForm );


});

//----------------Funcionando-------------
function changeTab() {
$(".js-update-object").click(function () {
 $('#tab-create-update').trigger('click')

  var btn = $(this);  // <-- HERE
  $.ajax({
    url: btn.attr("data-url"),  // <-- AND HERE
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#create-update").html(data.html_form);
      }
  });

});

};

  //carrega a tabela assim que a página entrar.
        $.ajax({
          url: '/list/',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            $("#list").html(data.html_list);
          }
        });
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('list/', views.list_equipaments, name='list'),
    path('create/', views.create_equipaments, name='create'),
    path('update/<int:id>/', views.update_equipaments, name='update'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from example.forms import ArvoreModelForm
from example.models import Arvore


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'example/index.html')


def list_equipaments(request):
    data = {}
    queryset = Arvore.objects.all()
    context = {'equipamentos': queryset}
    data['html_list'] = render_to_string('example/list.html',
                                         context,
                                         )

    return JsonResponse(data)


def save_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False

    context = {'form': form}

    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)

    return JsonResponse(data)


def create_equipaments(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArvoreModelForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = ArvoreModelForm()

    return save_form(request, form, 'example/create.html')


def update_equipaments(request, id):
    queryset = get_object_or_404(Arvore, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArvoreModelForm(request.POST, instance=queryset)
    else:
        form = ArvoreModelForm(instance=queryset)

    return save_form(request, form, 'example/update.html')
```

Another problem is that as the create / update tab serves both to create a new object and to update when I click the edit button, sometimes the empty form loads and not with the information about the object.

github: https://github.com/alexandrerod/single-page-crud

Comment: Guess the line of code where the problem might be.

Comment: Hi , why you have `changeTab()` as well as `$(".js-update-object").click..` event on same button ?